# How to get the selected ComboBox value in wix toolset?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have used `WIXUI_INSTALLDIR` template to bundle the installer. Here I have a custom form between welcome dialog and license dialog which consist of three `ListItem`s inside `Combobox`.

[image]

I tried to access the dropdown value with `bind.property.SK_Version`. For example, `<Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name="!(bind.property.SK_Version)">`. However it always return the value of first item in the list. Can you suggest me the best way to get selected value from combobox in wix toolset.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bind variables are a build time concept.  At runtime, MSI uses Properties.  There is a property associated with your combobox and each selection has a value and a display text.  The value gets assigned to the property.  From there you need to use a Set Property custom action to build your INSTALLLOCATION property based on the value of that property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/combobox-table